# Not able to add footnote and caption below a table in Latex

Tags: latex, tabular

I am creating a table using tabularx package, and adding figtext and caption in the table package. I want both the footnote and the caption below the table, but as soon as I add a caption, the footnotes disappear. My code is as below:

The main.tex file has the below code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{frame}
\center
\input{MangoShare}
\label{mangoshare}
\end{frame}
```

MangoShare.tex is the reference which is being called to the main.tex.

```
\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[h!]
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] 
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\small
\\[-1.8ex]
& & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Percentage Share} \\\\[-1.8ex]
\cline{3-8} \\[-1.8ex]
                 & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{B}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{C}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{D}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{E}  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{F} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Mango} & 0.58 & 0.56 & 0.92 & 0.22 & 0.72 & 0.033 \\
\tiny
\end{tabularx}
\hline 
\hline %\\[-1.8ex]
\figtext{\\[-1.8ex]\emph{Notes:} Controls Used} \\[-1.8ex]
\caption{Mango Share}
\end{table}
\end{centre}
```

Any help on this front would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] in a single codeblock so we can directly copy and try it without puzzling together your code fragments?

Comment: I've seen such nonsensical usage of  `\\[-1.8ex]` a couple of time in the last few weeks. Is this the result of some program like a table generator or something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130791/how-do-we-wrap-text-in-a-longtable-in-overleaf#comment115146502_65130791 is still true!

Comment: No, this just gives me the desired space between the hline/cline and row test. And also, I have tried to write a reproducible code. I somehow feel the issue is with how I am calling the table in main.tex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `table` is a floating environment, meant to move around in your document to get a nice looking output. If you wrap it in a static environment like `center` or `frame` it can't do that!
- `\hline` is for lines inside a `tabular` environment, don't use them outside (or better don't use them at all, the rules from the `booktab` package are much better)
- it makes no sense to wrap cells into `\multicolumn{1}...` remove all these unnecessary commands. They can destroy alignment of your table cells
- don't use `\\[-1.8ex]` in places where there is no active row. They'll mess up table lines etc, see [Why are the vertical lines in my table different lengths?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67926594/2777074)
- if you want to change the font size of your `tabular`, do this outside.
- `\figtext` is not defined.
- `\cmidrule` gives better spacing than `\cline`
- the floating specifier `[h!]` will most likely result in bad image placement, better use `[htbp]` to give latex more options

--

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}
%\center
%\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
%\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] 
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{}}
%\small
%\\[-1.8ex]
& & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Percentage Share} \\%[-1.8ex]
\cmidrule{3-8} %\\[-1.8ex]
                 & &A &B   &C   &D   &E  &F \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Mango} & 0.58 & 0.56 & 0.92 & 0.22 & 0.72 & 0.033 \\
%\tiny
\end{tabularx}
%\hline 
%\hline %\\[-1.8ex]

\bigskip

\emph{Notes:} Controls Used

\caption{Mango Share}
\label{mangoshare}
\end{table}
%\end{centre}

%\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Removing figtext and other redundant codes worked! :)